# One pass distributed clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering, sequential-analysis

I am working on clustering of data streams. For my purpose [Sequential Leader Clustering (SLC)](http://www.teco.edu/tea/unsup/overview.html#Sequential_Leader_Clustering_Algorithm) have given fair result, as i need not give number of clusters (like k in k means), which require some prior knowledge about data, and this is not affordable in Real time data streams ( The algorithm need to be strictly one pass over data).

Now, I'm looking forward to extend this method for distributed systems (such as map-reduce framework). The data streams is being collected by multiple nodes.

Can i just run SLC in individual nodes, and combine the result without much more difficulties. Or there is some other trick that i can apply for this.

Or is there any other algorithms, that i need to look for?

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? You might look into min-hash and other kinds of locality sensitive hashing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I am working with the streams of bitstrings (256 bits). The similarity measure for this is similar to jaccard similarity, i.e. # of 1's in (ANDed of 2 bitstrings)/ # of 1's in (ORed of 2 bitstrings). As far as i have understood, i cannot permute to the different combinations of min-wise hashing (because the elements in the strings are just 1 or 0). So , is there is any hashing for this similarity and data type???